# Generate PDF from aspx page using abcpdf.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, abcpdf

I have one web page url and i want to convert it to PDF.I used abcpdf.net in my webpage and its working fine in local host but its not working in server.I have installed abcpdf.net 6.1 version and added abcpdf.dll in my bin folder.my server is windows server 2008 r2. If there is a version problem ,please give me a suggestion.

here is my code:

```
string projectid = partnerid;
string versionid = DDLVersion.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Trim();
string serverurl = "http://serverurl/Design/Pro/Previewtopdf.aspx?PID=" + projectid + "&versionID=" + versionid + "";

        Doc theDoc = new Doc();
        theDoc.Rect.Inset(10, 30);

        theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
        int theID;
        theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl(serverurl);

        while (true)
        {
            theDoc.FrameRect(); // add a black border
            if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
                break;
            theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
            theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++)
        {
            theDoc.PageNumber = i;
            theDoc.Flatten();
        }
        theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("report.pdf"));
        theDoc.Clear();
        Response.Redirect("report.pdf");
```

Comment: Define not working, can you post an exception, or the result you are getting and what you are expecting?

Comment: Make double sure that all references to DLLs are non-GAC.

Comment: @ SynerCoder:Thanks for your response. I just want to convert my webpage to PDF file.i am not getting PDF when i generate it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your problem is in:

```
    theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("report.pdf"));

    Response.Redirect("report.pdf");
```

Make sure you are saving the report.pdf in the directory of your current request. Check if the report.pdf is idd in the right server directory. I quess it is saved somewhere else.